# Spring не может загрузить драйвер mysql (com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-11

Spring Boot проект при запуске выдает ошибку, что не может загрузить драйвер mysql (com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
> at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97)
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:223)
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:175)
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:43)
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:85)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
> ... 90 more

В application.properties выделяет почему-то красным "cj.jdbc.Driver":

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_users
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

В pom.xml указал следующие зависимости:

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.authorization</groupId>
    <artifactId>authorizationservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>AuthorizationService</name>
    <description>Service for user authorization</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <mysql-version>5.1.47</mysql-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Сам Hibernate сконфигурировал так:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "config"})
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig {
    private static Logger logger= LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernateConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = null;
        try {
            dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_users?useSSL=false");//"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbfastwater?useSSL=false"
            dataSource.setUsername("root");
            dataSource.setPassword("root");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("MysqlDataSource bean cannot be created!", e);
        }
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProp = new Properties();
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        hibernateProp.put("connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", true);
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", 3);
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 10);
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size", 50);
        
        return hibernateProp;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() throws IOException {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("entity","dao","service");
        sessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws IOException {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager=new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

Ещё Spring делает предупреждение, что не нравится мой конфигурационный файл Hibernate, не мэпит он его:

> Unmapped spring configuration files: HibernateConfig.java

Попробовал в pom.xml прописать текущею версию mysql-connector:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

> Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not create JPA EntityManager; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Где-то ошибка в конфигурировании, но где не могу понять

Comment: В application.properties пробовал менять 'spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver' на "spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' и убирать из зависимостей pom.xml mysql-connector - результат тот же

Comment: Пробую менять mysql-connector в настройках подключения БД MySQL в IDEA: Test connection проходит, только тогда, когда ставлю mysql-connector 5.1.47 (класс - com.mysql.jdbc.Driver), а когда пытаюсь ставить коннектор версии выше (1-н из последних) 8.0.13 (класс -com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver) - Test connection не проходит.

Comment: Может это быть связано с тем, что у меня open jdk стоят, а не oracle jdk?

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы было в следующей конфигурации:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_users?
useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```